# Prolog no operand Predicates

Tags: prolog

I am examining a Prolog example as a tutorial. In this example I have a predicate with Zero operand like this:

```
print_all_solutions :-
   findall(_,print_solution,_).
```

how can I call `print_all_solution` in the console? 
When I ask this in the Prolog console I get nothing:

```
?- print_all_solutions
```

no answer, also :

```
?- print_all_solutions.
```

no answer.

While i get correct answers to other questions like:

```
 ?- goal(state([],right,[a,b,c,d],12)).
true.

 ?- goal(state([],right,[a,b,c,d],19)).
false.
```

How should I ask a question about predicates with no operand ( /0 ), to see the solution in the console?

Comment: How is print_solutions defined. It all depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is that either `init(State)` or, more probably, `solve(State,Solution,EndState)` don't work.

You need to debug: enter these commands after you consulted the source file

```
?- leash(-all),trace.
?- print_solution.
```

and you'll get some clue from the Prolog engine

Comment: Thank you, tried it, trace answered TRUE but still no answer to `print_solution`.


`?-  leash(-all),trace.`


`true.`




`[trace]  ?- print_solution.`
no answer!

Answer (score 0):

I simply typed this in the console:

```
findall(_,print_all_solutions,_).
```

and i get the answer.

Comment: It's strange that this would give any answer, but entering `print_all_solutions.` gives no answer. `findall(_,print_all_solutions,_).` just collects all of the answers provided by `print_all_solutions`.